# How to add class to a tag on different condition using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have two div tag like

```
<div class="abc xyz">
  <p>lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
<div class="abc">
  <p>lorem ipsum </p>
</div>
```

I want to add another class to div tag if it contains classes "abc" & "xyz" and only one class condition.

I tried to like this but didn't get what I actually want.

```
if($( "div" ).hasClass( abc) && $( "div" ).hasClass( "xyz" ))
{
$(this).addClass('thirdclass');
}
else($("div").hasClass("abc")
{ $(this).addClass('fourthclass'); }
```

I don't want to add both the thirdclass and fourthclass.
How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use,

```
$("div.abc.xyz").addClass("thirdClass")
```

This will add the new class 'thirdClass' to all the div elements who has 'abc' and 'xyz' as its classname.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lv5cn8xy/203/)

**Edit as per the updated question**

```
$("div.abc.xyz").addClass("thirdClass")
$("div.abc:not(.xyz)").addClass("thirdClass")
```

Comment: How can I implement this for some condition? I just updated the qn.